# Regarding the application to increase the quota limit for the youtube data api

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to increase the quota limit for the Youtube Data API. If I apply and am approved, do I have to pay a fee for the increased amount of quota?
If so, how will the fee be paid?
Can I pay with Google Cloud Credits?
Is there a limit to the number of quota applications I can apply for?